# Python to insert quotes to column in CSV

Tags: python

I have no knowledge of python.
What i want to be able to do is create a script that will edit a CSV file so that it will wrap every field in column 3 around quotes. I haven't been able to find much help, is this quick and easy to do? Thanks.

```
column1,column2,column3
1111111,2222222,333333
```

Comment: Do you mean "wrap quotes around every field in column 3"? Also, why do you want to do this? Quoting is only necessary in a few special cases.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly crude solution, very specific to your request (assuming your source file is called "csvfile.csv" and is in C:\Temp).

```
import csv

newrow = []
csvFileRead = open('c:/temp/csvfile.csv', 'rb')
csvFileNew = open('c:/temp/csvfilenew.csv', 'wb')

# Open the CSV
csvReader = csv.reader(csvFileRead, delimiter = ',')

# Append the rows to variable newrow
for row in csvReader:
    newrow.append(row)

# Add quotes around the third list item
for row in newrow:
    row[2] = "'"+str(row[2])+"'"

csvFileRead.close()

# Create a new CSV file
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFileNew, delimiter = ',')

# Append the csv with rows from newrow variable
for row in newrow:
    csvWriter.writerow(row)

csvFileNew.close()
```

There are MUCH more elegant ways of doing what you want, but I've tried to break it down into basic chunks to show how each bit works.

Comment: For anyone with a simpler use case: use `csv.QUOTE_ALL` in your writer in case you want to quote all cells in all columns.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
filename = 'file.csv'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        row[2] = "'%s'" % row[2]
```

And then write it back in the csv file.