# How to wrap a CSV column with single quotes

Tags: python, csv, terminal, quotes

How can I use a Python script to wrap a CSV column with single quotes? 
I am trying to use the terminal to accomplish this task.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is a self answered question ... of questionable worth...

Comment: Please note that, although [self-answered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) are OK, they must still meet the basic requirements for both the question and the answer.

Comment: I wonder if it is considered seriab downvoting if i downvote q and a... sorry Raj, but If I ever had the need for this, I probably would use the csv module for it and configure it for quoting. You are using simply string manipulation which can go southwards fast.

Comment: Damn, didn't expect this reaction for my first Q&A. I'll take it down. :/ @PatrickArtner I had operated this on a 10k line CSV file and it had worked perfectly.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924249/adding-quotes-and-a-tab-to-each-element-in-a-csv-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) module to manipulate csv. It's there for not writing this kind of code again, and not having to bother with csv dialects (different delimiters e.g.) and when to quote etc. etc.

Read through [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) to appreciate what it does for you and why you should be using it.

```
import sys
import csv


reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Call with `python test.py < check.py > check_out.py`:

check.py:

```
bla,blubb,test
foo,,bar
bingo,bongo,bong
```

check_out.py:

```
"bla","blubb","test"
"foo","","bar"
"bingo","bongo","bong"
```

Other similar questions:

- [Adding quotes and a tab to each element in a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924249/adding-quotes-and-a-tab-to-each-element-in-a-csv-file)
- [Python to insert quotes to column in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782712/python-to-insert-quotes-to-column-in-csv)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Python script:

```
import sys
import re

def addQuotes( str ):
    matches = re.match( '^".*"$', str )
    if matches == None:
        return "'" + str + "'"
    return str

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    parts = line.split( ',' )
    newParts = map( addQuotes, parts )
```

After that, run the following command on the terminal:

> python QuoteCSV.py < old.csv > new.csv

Side note: If you want to wrap with Double quotes, you can change the return statement of the addQuotes function to say:

```
return '"'+str+'"'
```